# randomGenerator avoid duplicates in a row

Tags: android, eclipse, random, duplicates

I have a question regarding the following code

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(4);
    String wordList[] = new String[4];
    {
        wordList[0] = "Red";
        wordList[1] = "Blue";
        wordList[2] = "Green";
        wordList[3] = "Orange";


    }

String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];
```

This code works fine however I would like to know if it was possible to get it to not pick the same word two times in a row. For example, if it just selected "Red" then it would not pick "Red" again the next consecutive time. I read something about DISTINCT but I'm not sure if that's along the right path.

Here is the code for the button which uses this

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_random_text);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);
                String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];
                textView.setText(wordToDisplay);
```

Thankyou for your help

Comment: is this inside a method or a loop or something?

Comment: @IonutHulub I have a button using the string String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];

Comment: @IonutHulub edited my question to add more code

Comment: I was talking about the `int randInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(4)` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go for list and remove color once used:

```
private static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
private static Random random = new Random();
public static void fillList(){
    arrayList.add("Red");
    arrayList.add("Blue");
    arrayList.add("Green");
    arrayList.add("Orange");
}
public static String getNextRandomColor(){
    if(arrayList.isEmpty()){
        fillList();
    }
    return arrayList.remove(random.nextInt(arrayList.size()));
}
```

Comment: this is a very bad answer cause after 4 iterations the list will be empty and he won't be able to get a word again.

Comment: I want to be able to use the list over and over again

Comment: @SudarNimalan thanks! and this would change my implementation of my button correct?

Comment: yes you have to replace textView.setText(wordToDisplay); with textView.setText(getNextRandomColor());.  and avoid create Random randomGenerator = new Random(); again and again, create one and use nextInt, that will give you more random numbers.

Comment: @SudarNimalan got it! Also, I don't understand what you mean by saying to avoid create Random randomGenerator = newRandom();

Comment: create random = new Random();, as static variable,use that to call nextInt method whenever you want a random number. if you called nextInt multiple time from  the same object, you will get more randomized number pattern, compare to create each time new object and call nextInt method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two way (probably more but two that I can think of right now):

1) Create a function that uses a global variable to store the last generated random number.
It will look something like this:

```
int myRand(int i) {
  int aux;
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();

  do {
    aux = randomGenerator.nextInt(i);
  } while (aux != lastRandGenerated);

  lastRandGenerated = aux;

  return aux;
}
```

, where lastRandGenerated is a global variable that you initialize to 0.

Then you use this function to generate random numbers.

2) You can create a class that has a function very similar to the one above and then instantiate an object of that class and use that to generate your random numbers. In the class create a static variable that will remember the last generated random number. Use that instead of the global variable.

Comment: This is my first app, so I'm a little new to this. Could you elaborate on your first method please? I understand creating the global variable  but how I link that to my generator I don't understand

Comment: You don't link it to the generator. You create a function that (in a loop) creates a random number and saves it as `aux`, then it checks to see if it is equal to the global variable and if it is it means that it must generate a number again. it does so until the number generated is different then the last generated number, then it returns it. just create a global variable called `lastRandGenerated`, copy paste the function in your program and call it like `myRand(4)` instead of `randomGenerator.nextInt(4)`

Answer (score 0):

The specifics are a bit out of my league but as a math problem there are 24 combinations (4 * 3 * 2 * 1). As heavy handed as this might sound, worst case you could work out all the combos and then pick a one out of 24 random.